# Object.style.filter="Flipv" its working fine in Internet explorer. How can i do in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I want to convert the  to flipVertical. I tried the `object.style.filter="Flipv"` its not working in firefox. Please make it.....

Comment: filters like the one you described are IE specific (proprietary).  You can find out more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx).  For firefox you will need to find a different approach.  If you find something that works in FF it will probably also work in IE since FF relies less on nonstandard extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms673539%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are implemented in only Internet Explorer.

Instead, you can use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/transform) from CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/

In this case, you need `transform: scaleY(-1)`.

A JavaScript example for Firefox:

```
document.getElementById('x').style.MozTransform = "scaleY(-1)";
```

CSS3 transforms are also [supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d).

Answer (score 0):

you can use also CANVAS of firefox